# Difference resultant aerodynamics force on an airfoil and a flat plate

Tags: fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics

From basic airfoil theory the following free body diagram can be determined for a two dimensional asymmetric airfoil:

[image]

Here the direction of the resultant force is governed by the geometry of the airfoil section.

However, I'm unsure on how the direction of the resultant force is affected when instead of an airfoil a two dimensional flat plate is considered.
Do the resultant force $R$ and normal force $N$ just overlay each other as shown below (my suspicion)?

[image]

Comment: Due to shear stress at the surface, there will be a force parallel to the plate.

Comment: ...small force.

Comment: Meaning that the $R$ force can only be decomposed in the $L$ and $D$ force if the $A$ force is neglected?

Comment: You don't have to neglect it. If you are doing an experiment you can measure it. If you want a decent estimate you can use boundary layer theory to get the shear stress and integrate over the plate surface to get the force. If you are doing simulations you can calculate the axial force similarly.

Comment: Here's an [*excellent, readable, exposition*](http://www.av8n.com/how/). In particular, it discusses airfoil shape, air flow, and all forms of drag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direction of the Resultant force $R$ is always dependent on the direction of the $V\infty$
But however, the direction/orientation of the Normal force $N$ is dependent on the orientation of the body itself ($N$ is perpendicular to the body and axial force $A$ is parallel to the body.)

In the above case, since there is not much of surface interaction, the lift component $L$ is considerably higher than the drag component $D$ at lower angles of attack $\alpha$. For the given $\alpha$, Resultant force $R$ will be in a different orientation to the Normal force $N$ (You cannot ignore the tiny axial force $A$.) As the $\alpha$ increases, $R$ moves more and more closer to $N$ as the axial force $A$ decreases in the magnitude.

$R$ and $N$ will overlay each other when the angle of attack $\alpha$ is $90 ^{\circ}$.

Answer (score 0):

That would sure make it easy to figure out the drag on the flat plate if you knew the lift: $$ D = R \sin(\alpha)$$ and $$ L = R\cos(\alpha)$$ so that $$D = L \tan(\alpha)$$  and the lift to drag ratio is simply $$\frac{L}{D}=\cot(\alpha)$$ Common sense should tell you that can't be right.  Back to reality...

Comment: For an infinitely thin plate, lift is zero for zero angle of incidence, so your lift expression needs a bit of work.